# Figure out the pattern

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

$0,4,8,21,52,65,96$

Given this set of numbers figure out the pattern they follow and write down the next seven numbers in the sequence.

Hint:

> The next two numbers in the pattern are 1 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is:

> Add 4, then reverse the digits.

The next 7 numbers are:

> 1, 5, 9, 31, 53, 75, 97
>
>  This is in the OEIS, as sequence [A00368](http://oeis.org/A003608).

Comment: Do I need to cite anything? I feel like I should have...

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy If you found the puzzle somewhere else, please give the source it comes from. If you came up with it independently, there's no need to cite anything. (That being said, I wouldn't recommend number sequence puzzles anyway - they're generally very low quality, at least in my opinion.)

Comment: Ok, I will use that as my standard practice. Thank you!